# In gnuplot, how to search a string in a file and use the value after the string?

Tags: gnuplot

I am using gnuplot.
I have a datafile that is written in blocks.
Every block contains a header written in the following way 
`;low temp = 1.997 K;high temp = 2.001 K;avg. temp = 2.000 K;`

After every header I have columns that contain a position, signal,..,etc

```
,3784541949.42929,13.4982557296753,0.0167865138500929,0.123592436313629
,3784541949.45429,13.6974411010742,0.0387519747018814,0.145576447248459
```

and so on.

I want the get the value avg. temp = 2.00002518892288 as a variable. So I could plot the columns after every header with different color according to the temperature indicated in the header.

Previously, I had written a similar code

`plot   for[ivar=1:300:1]   rawdata1 every ::(ivar*24+2)::(ivar*24+25) u 8:($11+ ivar/sepy):($4) w p pt 7 ps 0.3 palette noti "" ,\`

But in that case there was only one block with the columns: position, signal, temperature.
I am trying to get something similar to the following plot. The issue is that the new files are written in blocks with headers as I mentioned above.

Do you have any idea?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean with blocks? Are the blocks maybe separated by single or double empty lines or not, or do all blocks have a certain fixed number of lines? Is is correct that header lines use `;` for start,end and separation, whereas data lines use `,` for start and separation?

Comment: There is not separation with empty lines. Every block has an exact number of lines. The headers use `;` to start and separation but not to end. Data lines use `,` for separation.  The file has a main  header. After that there is a header starting with `;`  it contains the conditions of the points,  every condition is separated by `;` For example `; low temp = 2.1 K;high temp = 2.40 K;avg. temp = 2.24 K`  .it finishes without `;` then there are exactly 201 rows with data points separated with `,` after those 201 rows a new header separated with `;` starts again.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky. We can set both comma and semicolon as field separators, then try to extract a number from the 4th columnhead. Since we know the exact format of the column headers we know that the numeric value is in the substring header[13:*].  The iteration grabs each block N by skipping over all the previous lines and then reading only the exact number of points.

```
  # Plot signal in column 3 at x-coordinate in column 2
  # Use the avg temperature as a title attached to the line of points

  set datafile sep ',;'
  set key textcolor variable
  unset key
  set colorbox
  plot for [N=0:*] 'data' skip 1+(202*N) every 1::0::200   \
       using 2:3:(real(columnhead(4)[13:*]))   \
       with lp pt 7 lc palette   \
       title '     '.columnhead(4) at end
```

[image]

I generated a few short blocks of junk data to test the commands, and tested with current gnuplot (version 5.2.8).  You probably don't want the titles but they helped me confirm that the coloring was correct.

**Edit**

The logic of the command may become clearer if the color extraction is split out into a separate function:

```
  color(q) = real(columnhead(q)[13:*])
  plot for [N=0:*] 'data' skip 1+(202*N) every 1::0::200   \
       using 2:3:(color(4))   \
       with lp pt 7 lc palette
```

Comment: maybe needs to be mentioned `columnhead(q)[13:*]` will not work in gnuplot <=5.2.8, but seems to work in gnuplot 5.4.0